# How do I get args typescript types from graphql query and mutation fields?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I'm having some trouble with using typscript and graphql. I cant seem to get all of it typed.
How can I get typed args and parent properties in Root query and mutation fields?

For example:
Server:

```
export interface IContext {
  res: Response;
  req: Request;
  prisma: PrismaClient;
}

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query,
});

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ req, res }: { req: Request; res: Response }) => ({
      req,
      res,
      prisma,
    }),
  });
```

Root Query:

```
const query = new GraphQLObjectType<any, IContext>({
  name: 'QueryType',
  fields: {
    notifications: {
      type: new GraphQLList(NotificationType),
      args: { filter: { type: FindManyNotificationArgs } },
      resolve: async (parent, args, { req, prisma }) => {
        // parent is any 
        // args is [argName: string]: any;
        //req and prisma are typed only due to IContext interface at root query
        try {
          isAuth(req);
          return await prisma.notification.findMany({ ...args.filter });
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      },
    },
    messages: {
      type: new GraphQLList(MessageType),
      args: { filter: { type: FindManyMessageArgs } },
      resolve: async (parent, args, { req, prisma }) => {
        // parent is any 
        // args is [argName: string]: any;
        //req and prisma are typed only due to IContext interface at root query
        try {
          isAuth(req);
          return await prisma.message.findMany({ ...args.filter });
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Message types:

```
export const MessageType = new GraphQLObjectType<Message, IContext>({
  name: 'Message',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    ...
    content: { type: GraphQLString },
    hasAttachment: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    created: { type: GraphQLDateTime },
    updated: { type: GraphQLDateTime },
    expired: { type: GraphQLDateTime },
  }),
});

export const FindManyMessageArgs = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'FindManyMessageArgs',
  fields: () => ({
    where: { type: MessageWhereInput },
    orderBy: { type: MessageOrderByInput },
    take: { type: GraphQLInt },
    skip: { type: GraphQLInt },
  }),
});

export const MessageWhereInput: GraphQLInputObjectType =
  new GraphQLInputObjectType({
    name: 'MessageWhereInput',
    fields: () => ({
      id: { type: GraphQLID },
      personId: { type: GraphQLInt },
      person: { type: PersonWhereInput },
      personDocumentStatusId: { type: GraphQLInt },
      personDocumentStatus: { type: PersonDocumentStatusWhereInput },
      content: { type: StringFilter },
      created: { type: GraphQLDateTime },
      updated: { type: GraphQLDateTime },
      expired: { type: GraphQLDateTime },
      AND: { type: MessageWhereInput },
      OR: { type: GraphQLList(MessageWhereInput) },
      NOT: { type: MessageWhereInput },
    }),
  });
```

How do I properly define typescript types to get everything typed in rootquery and mutationquery from my defined types

like from

```
type: new GraphQLList(NotificationType), (This should be parent in resolve function)
args: { filter: { type: FindManyNotificationArgs } },) (This should be args in resolve function)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that args cannot be typed automatically for safety, as args can be anything.